# character encoding UTF-8 não funcionando

Tags: java-ee, codificação-de-caracteres

Sei que a questão já foi comentada inúmeras vezes em diversos blogs e fóruns mundo afora, mas realmente não sei o que pode estar ocasionando, pois acho que na configuração de meu projeto está tudo ok:

**paginas *.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JooceBox v1.0</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Além disso setei como parâmetro na própria conexão com o banco de dados:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/viatgedb?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

Mesmo com tais configurações quando vou salvar algum registro com acentos o mesmo fica da seguinte forma:

**'JoÃ£o Manuel', 'GalÃ£o Bonin'**

Comment: Já tentou usar `ISO 8859-1`?

Comment: Oi @Edi.Gomes já tentei, mas sem sucesso

Comment: Deveria funcionar com tudo isso. Mas verifique se sua tabela no banco de dado está como `UTF-8` também. Se você logar os dados na camada de persistência, os acentos estão corretos ou não. É muito importante isolar o problemas antes de qualquer tentativa, isto é, se ocorre na interpretação do HTTP ou na comunicação com o BD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi o problema seguindo esse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141403/utf-8-encoding-in-spring-mvc-problem-with-forms).

Parece que nos navegadores modernos no momento em que é feito o *submmit* do formulário pelo *metodo* **POST** não é enviado o *header HTTP **Accept-Encoding***. Logo a especificação padrão dos *servlets* especifica o *encode* **Latin-1/ISO-8859-1**.

Simplesmente o que precisa ser feito é adicionar o *filter* `SetCharacterEncodingFilter` no *web.xml* como o primeiro no arquivo.

Já para requisições do tipo **GET** basta editar a *tag* `<connector>` arquivo *server.xml* (*Apache Tomcat*) adicionando os seguintes atributos: `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"`